# Не удается спарсить

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
test=soup.findAll('div',class_='main')#.find('h1').text   надо получить значение 'h1'
print(test)
```

Вот сайт

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `test=soup.findAll('div',class_='main')[0].find('h1').text`

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.